# best in place edit not working on live site

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

`best in place` edit not working on the production. I am using the text field with pencil on click on that text field must be shown up. When I ran javascript code at my website console it works.

Here is the code:

```
jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place();
```

Image of my site UI where I have used best in place:

[image: Pencile in the image open the text field to edit text]

this is my html code

```
     <div class="col-md-7">
   <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
     <%= best_in_place_if can?(:update_organization_with_bip, @organization), @organization, :maximum_sponsor_spend_per_month, :as => :input, activator: "#edit-sponsor_max_spend_per_month", url: {action: :update_organization_with_bip , id: @organization.id},inner_class: "form-control", :classes => 'bounce_on_success' %>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-1 text-left">
     <%= link_to("<i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>".html_safe, "javascript:void(0);", id: "edit-sponsor_max_spend_per_month",class: "text-danger") %>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: any browser issues on prod console?

Comment: might be javascript load earlier then html text so that it's working in prod first

Comment: have you precompile in your production, you may try RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile

Comment: Thank you all for replying.
1. No there are no errors on the console.
2. @TusharPal sorry but I didn't understand you. What I need to do.
3. Yes, I have precompiled my assets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar issue (deployed on heroku)
Using gem of best_in_place 3.0.3

I see that helper work and generate html structure.

After a lot of time i found that only this helped me:
(put in show view)

```
<%= content_for :javascript do %>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place();
    });
  </script>
<% end %>
```

Yes, i have similar in my js file in assets js file that working locally

Comment: probably the issue is with how the gem render stuff and when its binding `.best_in_place` js method, unfortunately haven't time to research